# Linear Regression: How to transform a independent variable following somewhat of a power function

Tags: regression, machine-learning, data-transformation, linear-model

I am trying to run a linear regression for a dependent variable where one of the independent variable shows non linear relationship. Please see attachment for the scatter plot. Please suggest what should be a suitable transformation for this variable for a linear relationship.[image: Scatter plot relationship]

Comment: This looks more like a deterministic relationship than a probabilistic one, so one wonders why regression is applicable. As far as determining the function form goes, you might look into universal approximators.

Comment: Answers to your question are unlikely to advance your analysis of these data.  Consider asking instead about the actual statistical problem you face.

Comment: Thanks, I will frame the whole scenario and ask a different question